# app crashing after insert entity to my room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm new to the room database and I'm trying to make one database to insert words in my list(its gonna get 2 words from me every time)
so I want to test it but I got this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.paradise.personaldictionary, PID: 9307
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paradise.personaldictionary/com.paradise.personaldictionary.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File EN/FA_DB contains a path separator
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File EN/FA_DB contains a path separator
        at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2671)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getDatabasePath(ContextImpl.java:865)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getDatabasePath(ContextWrapper.java:341)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:371)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:622)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:399)
        at com.paradise.personaldictionary.roomdb.WordsDao_Impl.insert(WordsDao_Impl.java:77)
        at com.paradise.personaldictionary.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.kt:55)
        at com.paradise.personaldictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

and this the lines of error he shows me to fix it

```
at com.paradise.personaldictionary.roomdb.WordsDao_Impl.insert(WordsDao_Impl.java:77)
        at com.paradise.personaldictionary.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.kt:55)
        at com.paradise.personaldictionary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
```

it's about my insert function

this is my insert fun in my wordsDao class

```
 @Insert
    fun insert( words: Words)
```

and my fun test() in activity main

```
fun test(){
        val db: AppDatabase = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this)
        var firstword = Words("Hello","salam")
        db.wordsDao().insert(firstword)
        var getDb = db.wordsDao().getAll()
    }
```

UPDATE
the new error

```
  Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->mLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->throwIfNotOpenLocked()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteSession;->setTransactionSuccessful()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/ContentValues;->isEmpty()Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->getThreadDefaultConnectionFlags(Z)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->yieldIfContendedHelper(ZJ)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
I/chatty: uid=10415(com.paradise.personaldictionary) ection primary] identical 1 line
W/sonaldictionar: Accessing hidden method Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase;->yieldIfContendedHelper(ZJ)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
V/StudioTransport: Handling agent command 1200 for pid: 19307.
I/sonaldictionar: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1550 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
```

there are tons of lines like this in my logcat and debug window

Comment: can you post full MainActivity.kt  file

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File EN/FA_DB contains a path separator`

It looks like when you initialized your database you  passed it an invalid filename.

Somewhere you are doing something like this:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "EN/FA_DB")
```

Using `"EN/FA_DB"` is not allowed. You need to specify simply a filename which contains no path separators or other special characters. Something like `"test.db"`

Comment: It's working thanks, the app not crashing anymore but it's still not working. It says something about access denied in SQL. ill put the error in question

Comment: Those errors can probably be ignored. How do you know that "it does not work"?

Comment: What version of Android is your device (or emulator) running? What is your targetSDK?

Comment: Also, are you using any 3rd-party libraries in your app?